# React how to add Card element in Swiper slider by onClick event?

Tags: reactjs, addition, card

React how to add Card element in Swiper slider by onClick event ?

Comment: Can you provide code, of how how you are trying to approach and what issue are you facing currently?

Comment: That is You have to provide a reproducible example so that we can copy and run

Comment: Haven't tryed yet because currently I don't know how. I'm looking for ready-to use solution. I'll find it myself , it just takes time. Thnx for your kind responce

Comment: So per your question, I am able to understand that when the user clicks on the card element that card get's added to the Swiper slide?
am right?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. get's added to the Swiper slider as a new Slide

Answer (score 1):

I have created Code Sandbox Demo For Adding Card when they are click
[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-swartz-w415xk?file=/src/App.js)

Below is the code, give it a try. In this Demo the slide will be added to the end so you would need to slide to the end to check the new slide added.

```
import { useState } from "react";
// Import Swiper React components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";

// Import Swiper styles
import "swiper/css";

export default function App() {
  const [swipers, setSwipers] = useState([
    "Slide 1",
    "Slide 2",
    "Slide 3",
    "Slide 4"
  ]);

  const addSwiper = (swiper) => {
    setSwipers((prevSwipers) => prevSwipers.concat(swiper));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Swiper
        spaceBetween={50}
        slidesPerView={3}
        onSlideChange={() => console.log("slide change")}
        onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
      >
        {swipers.map((swiper, index) => (
          <SwiperSlide key={index}>{swiper}</SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => addSwiper("Add Swiper Card 1")}>
        Add Swiper Card 1 (Click on this to Add)
      </button>{" "}
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => addSwiper("Add Swiper Card 2")}>
        Add Swiper Card 2 (Click on this to Add)
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look through it.

Comment: If this was the one you were looking for, then Mark this answer as a Accepted Answer

Comment: Not actually. but anyway thank you so much for help